# Object Word.Application lotusscript

Tags: lotusscript, lotus

Getting error when I'm trying to use attribute for MS Word Object in lotusscript. My task is to append background picture in MSWord document, using lotusscript.

That is what i have:

```
Dim wrdApp As Variant
Dim wordFile As Variant
Dim ActiveDocument As Variant

Set wrdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
Set wordFile = GetObject( , "Word.Application")
filepath = "C:\TEST\" & object.Source
Call object.ExtractFile(filepath$)
wrdApp.Visible = True
Call wrdApp.activate
wrdApp.documents.open(filepath$)
Set ActiveDocument = wrdApp.activedocument

ActiveDocument.Shapes.AddPicture("C:\Users\bukhtiyarov_a\Desktop\1.jpg",_
False,True, 0,0,570,570).Select

ActiveDocument.ShapeRange.Name = "WordPictureWatermark518456249"
ActiveDocument.ShapeRange.PictureFormat.Brightness = 0.85
```

How i can apply (ShapeRange.PictureFormat.Brightness = 0.85) for my picture.
Thank you!

The error that I get is `Instance member SHAPERANGE does not exist` in the line `ActiveDocument.ShapeRange.Name = "WordPictureWatermark518456249"`

Comment: What happens? Any error? Doesn't it work?

Comment: Yes i've got an errors on line: (ActiveDocument.ShapeRange.Name = "WordPictureWatermark518456249")

Comment: And error is: Instance member SHAPERANGE does not exist

Comment: In my Word Visual Basic Editor "ShapeRange" is not an instance member of ActiveDocument... It is an instance member of selection... Your code does not even work natively in Word, why should it work in LotusScript?. AND: Always add the error to your post... Otherwise no one is willing to help without knowing the exact error message and the exact line where it happens.

Comment: I don't know the Word object model all that well, but it looks to like one of the following is what you want:

It looks like you should be doing something like this:

mySelection =ActiveDocument.Shapes.AddPicture("C:\Users\bukhtiyarov_a\Desktop\1.jpg",_
False,True, 0,0,570,570).Select

mySelection.ShapeRange(1).Name = "WordPictureWatermark518456249"
mySelection.ShapeRange(1)..PictureFormat.Brightness = 0.85

Comment: Or

ActiveDocument.Shapes.AddPicture("C:\Users\bukhtiyarov_a\Desktop\1.jpg",_
False,True, 0,0,570,570).Select
Selection.ShapeRange(1).Name = "WordPictureWatermark518456249"
Selection.ShapeRange(1)..PictureFormat.Brightness = 0.85

Comment: Hello again! 
Nope Richard it doesn't work, both of this variant which you offered for me.
In first variant: (mySelection = ActiveDocument.Shapes.AddPicture("C:\Users\bukhtiyarov_a\De‌​sktop\1.jpg",....)
I got an error: MicrosoftWord: "Select" is not a propperty
In second variant: (ActiveDocument.Shapes.AddPicture("C:\Users\bukhtiyarov_a\Des‌​ktop\1.jpg",......)
I got an error:
"Variant does not contain an object" on line (Selection.ShapeRange(1).Name = "WordPictureWatermark518456249" ) and it's justly, because we did not create the object "Selection".

Comment: Hi have you tested your code in VBA debugger ? (ALT-F11 inside word)

Comment: @umeli
Hi umeli!
Сourse i tested in VBA debugger and problem is not with VBA there worked perfectly, seem's like problem in me :)
I can't convert script which i got from VBA in Lotusscript.

Comment: @RichardSchwartz
Sorry Richard i suppose you did not got my last answers. And i repeat it for you.
Hello again! Nope Richard it doesn't work, both of this variant which you offered for me. In first variant: (mySelection = ActiveDocument.Shapes.AddPicture("C:\Users\bukhtiyarov_a\De‌‌​​sktop\1.jpg",....) I got an error: MicrosoftWord: "Select" is not a propperty

Comment: @RichardSchwartz
In second variant: (ActiveDocument.Shapes.AddPicture("C:\Users\bukhtiyarov_a\De‌​s‌​ktop\1.jpg",.....‌​.) I got an error: "Variant does not contain an object" on line (Selection.ShapeRange(1).Name = "WordPictureWatermark518456249" ) and it's justly, because we did not create the object "Selection".

Comment: @umeli
I just need to take some picture and paste it like background in Word document. I already tried different ways but still nothing. I just get an errors one by one.

Comment: I copied the .Select directly from your code. I assumed your code was syntactically correct.  The error message is telling you that .Select is not a property, I just checked, and it is a method. In LotusScript, the parameter list for a method is required even if it is empty, so you need .Select() instead of just .Select.

Comment: @RichardSchwartz
I realy appreciate your help, but result still the same. And error now is (Type mismatch) on line:
Set mySelection = ActiveDocument.Shapes.AddPicture("C:\Users\bukhtiyarov_a\Desktop\1.jpg",_
 False,True, 0,0,570,570).Select()
I don't know, maybe this is a Lotusscript feature. Or we should try to enter from other side? :)) What if i'll try to parse MSWord document in xml format and then i'll paste my picture, using xml?

Comment: No, it's not a LotusScript feature. It's a matter of getting the correct syntax and semantics. If it's saying type mismatch, that probably means the type returned by the Select() method doesn't match the type that you declared for mySelection. Did you declare it as a variant?

Comment: @RichardSchwartz
I found a solution! Promlem was very simple :))
 Set wordFile = GetObject(filepath , "Word.Document")
i'm not correctly define a variable. As you can see now variable (wordFile) this is a "Word.Document". But before i define this like a "Word.Application". That's why we've got an error. Anyway thanks everybody, because you gave me right way!

Comment: that's my end ver. script:
Dim wrdApp As Variant
 Dim wordFile As Variant 
Dim count As Integer  
 Set wrdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
 filepath = "C:\TEST\" & object.Source
 Call object.ExtractFile(filepath)
 Set wordFile = GetObject(filepath , "Word.Document")
 wordFile.Application.Visible = False
 If wordFile.ProtectionType <> -1 Then
  Print "Doc is protected"
 Else
  count = wordFile.Paragraphs.Count
  wordFile.Paragraphs(1).Range.Select
  rttext = wordFile.content.text 
 End If
 Call wordFile.Application.Quit()
 Set wordFile = Nothing
 Kill filepath

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub getWRDvalue(object)
    Dim wrdApp As Variant
    Dim wordFile As Variant
    Dim count As Integer

    Set wrdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    filepath = "C:\TEST\" & object.Source
    Call object.ExtractFile(filepath)
    Set wordFile = GetObject(filepath , "Word.Document")
    wordFile.Application.Visible = False
    If wordFile.ProtectionType <> -1 Then
        Print "Document is protected"
    Else
        count = wordFile.Paragraphs.Count
        wordFile.Paragraphs(1).Range.Select
        rttext = wordFile.content.text  
    End If
    Call wordFile.Application.Quit()
    Set wordFile = Nothing
    Kill filepath
End Sub
```